# Rudin PMA 3.2 (d) - why is this detail not mentioned in the theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits

Rudin PMA $3.2$ $(d)$ says:

> If $E \subseteq X$ and if $p$ is a limit point of $E$, then there is a sequence $\{p_n\}$ in $E$ such that $p = \lim_{n\to \infty} p_n$.

Why don't we add the fact that $$\forall n\geq0, p_n \neq p$$

in the theorem ?

Is it relevant ?

Comment: You can add it, but it is not necessary.  The main point is to get $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$ so that the convergence definition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Zhanxiong mentions in the comments, it is not necessary to have the restriction for this direction of the theorem, but you could add it and have a slightly stronger result with essentially the same proof (assuming $X$ is a metric space). If you want the converse to also be true then you do need to add that condition. That is, if there is a sequence $\{p_n\}$ in $E$ with each $p_n \ne p$ and $p_n \to p$ then $p$ is a limit point of $E$.